# c# any cool graphing libraries to graph performance data?

Tags: c#, image, graph, rendering, charts

Any one know of a tutorial or library or something that i could use to help me accomplish rendering a X-Y GRAPH for performance data or just data in general.

My goal is to have a final result looking something similar to

[image]

[This Chart rendered by RRD.](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/stream-pop.png)

So just to clarify i just want to render these type of images i don't want rich server controls as they are over kill in my eyes. DevExpress,ComponentOne,Tel..,MSChart,FusionCharts,Jplot,dygraph,Ifragestics,DotNetcharting,AMcharts are no goods...

Comment: dotnetCharting has already been evaluated and unless i can see a good demo of it id rather stay away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a RRD project called [NHawk](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHawk/NHawk.zip) (C# RRDTool Library for .Net and Mono) which is an initiative to provide a thin, complete RRDtool provider for the .Net and Mono framework. More details are available at "[C# Hooks For RRDTool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHawk.aspx)".

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft provides a really good, *free* charting library for ASP.NET and Winforms.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en

See it here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: I will second this. Once you learn how to bind data fast, it works great.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org) (open source, licensed under LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress
Telerik
Obout
ComponentOne

Comment: No, i have tried these as well please take alook at the picture.

Comment: Have you actually tried DevExpress charts?
http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Charting/screenshot_gallery.xml
I don't see why their 2D area graph wouldn't do what you're after, or a high-density 2D stacked bar graph with

Answer (score 0):

**[Fusion charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com)**

They also have a [free edition](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/).

Answer (score 0):

Just for info -- the [rrdtool trunk](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool-trac/browser/trunk/program) now contains dotnet bindings for public rrdlib functions.